Randomly adding rows from another datatable based on group and a probability
Suppose I have a dataframe called Main of this format - which will have a large combination of Region and Type of thousands of rows, with the Region/Type combination duplicated multiple times but with difference numbers in the Value column. This is a shortened version of the Main dataframe showing its format:
Region  Type    Value
A        1       600
A        2       700
A        2       750
B        1       700
B        1       500
B        2       900
B        2      1000


I also have an another dataframe Prob that consists of Region, Type and Probability. This is a fairly short table - 20 or 30 rows as the probability will always be fixed for a given combination of Region and Type. It's this table that is used as a lookup for Main to set the probability that is discussed further below. This table will be fairly short in size.
Region  Type   Probability
A        1       20%
A        2       30%
B        1       40%
B        2       90%

Stepping down each row in the Main table, I look up the probability from the dataframe Prob based on the Region and Type. Python then works out randomly based on the probability whether I'll add an extra row to the Main dataframe.
However, that extra row of data I'll add will be taken randomly from another even larger dataframe Extras which has the same form to Main:
Region  Type   Value
A        1       600
A        1       300
A        2       700
A        2       950
B        1       700
B        1        50
B        2       900
B        2      1200
B        2       300

BUT:
a) The random row I pull from Extras can only have the same Region and Type as in the Main dataframe - and
b) Once I've taken that row of data, I remove it from the Extras dataframe as I don't want to pull the same row twice from the Extras dataframe.
Am trying to understand how I get this done.
Using my small example here, in the end I'll have a Main dataframe for example that is something that looks like:
Region  Type    Value
A        1       600
A        2       700
A        2       750
B        1       700
B        1       500
B        2       900
B        2      1000
B        2       900
B        2       300

...where stepping through the seven rows of the Main dataframe, for Region B, Type 2 where there's 90% chance of pulling a new row into "Main" from Extras, we end up pulling two extra rows (whilst removing them from the Extras dataframe as we step through each row).
In my actual large data example, I have about 10000 rows in Main all with combinations of Region and Type of A/B and 1/2 all with probabilities of around 20% - so I'd expect to get around 2000 new rows added to the data from Extras table (which itself is about 40000 rows in size).

Can you have duplicated combinations of Region/Type in Main?

yes you can - the value field will likely be unique as the numbers are quite large.

And in the second one (with the probabilities?)

no - this is one is set - will only ever be the same probability for a given region and type.

(I've made edits accordingly in the main text)

OK, see below for an approach, you can repeat the process to more more rows after your "next calculation".

Assuming main/proba/extra as inputs, you can use the following steps:
# define keys
cols = ['Region', 'Type']

# convert string percent to float
# select rows based on probability
m = (proba['Probability'].str.strip('%').astype(float).div(100)
   > np.random.random(len(proba))
   )

# select random matching rows from "extra"
select = (extra.reset_index()
          .merge(proba.loc[m, cols])
          .groupby(cols).sample(n=1)
          .set_index('index')
          )

# add to "main", remove from "extra"
main = pd.concat([main, select])
extra.drop(select.index, inplace=True)

Example output:
# main
  Region  Type  Value
0      A     1    600
1      A     2    700
2      B     1    700
3      B     2    900
0      A     1    600
5      B     1     50

# extra
  Region  Type  Value
1      A     1    300
2      A     2    700
3      A     2    950
4      B     1    700
6      B     2    900
7      B     2    300


Just a quick comment before I try - will this work if there are many more columns like "Value" that contain further information (but are not necessarily in the calculation process)? Just looking at the code it suggests that's the case. Thanks for the help.

@Richard yes, it should keep other columns. It only relies on Region/Type

Just coming back to this and re-editing as not sure if you saw my last comment and whether it was clear enough - this is only working I believe if main and prob have the same lengths and same structure (Region, Type in first two rows) per above I'm looking to look up (Merge?) the probability from the Prob dataframe as in reality the main dataframe will have 1000s of rows and the Prob dataframe will only have about 20. I've edited the text above to hopefully clarify that.

@Richard no this is fully independent of the number of rows in main, in fact you could have an empty main DataFrame. Unless I misunderstood the logic, assuming M rows in main, P rows in proba and  E in extra, you will end up with M+X rows where X is a number between 0 and min(P, E). Why don't you give it a try and if it doesn't behave like expected, then provide a counter-example showing how it fails and what should be the expected output.

I just took an adapted version of the above using 7 rows in the "Main" and a few extra columns in "Extra" to pick from and set the Prob to 1 in each case so it's forced to pick rather than do it randomly. It only ever adds 4 rows to the new column: which is what happened when I applied it to some alternative data. Is the issue in the "len(proba)" bit of the code - i.e. it's only ever defining a length of calculation in keeping with the length of the prob dataframe (i.e. 4 rows)?

@Richard there must be something unclear in your logic. The way I understood it is you want to pick at most 1 row per row from extra, and this is done randomly because of sample. Please be aware that the way you're thinking of it might not the the way I understand it, so be explicit. Provide an example that demonstrates how my approach doesn't work. For starter explicit in your output where is row is coming from.

I've tried to add more detail to the example. In my actual data I have about 10000 rows. The prob table is small, about 20 rows with combinations of Region / Type where the probability is around 20% on average. So when we go through each row in the Main table and look-up on Region/Type in the Prob table I expect to pick about 2000 new rows from Extras table to add to the Main table. I think I've tried to explain it as best as I can. And yes, as you say I pick up no more than 1 row per row of extra.
